# Google Map with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

my problem is i want to show my registered site user on to google map  but dont know how to locate the user, means i dont know the latitude and longitude of every user . I am a newbie in google map so plz  help

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two possible ways of doing this.

1. **Ask the user to search a google map and place themselves on it.** Look here for an idea on how to do this http://www.designing4u.de/2008/08/google-maps-jquery-and-xml-saving-markers-with-user-input/
2. **Use an IP to Location database to find out the location based on their IP.** Look here for how to do this http://www.ip2nation.com/ip2nation

Comment: Thanks JOsh for such an awesome answer

Answer (score 4):

What location data do you have for your users? Cities, states, countries?

You might want to have a look at [Google's Geocoding APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding).

Comment: Thanks coomer im interested in cities

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to reliably locate a user using their IP address.  However if you are developing for a mobile device it may be possible to acquire their GPS coordinates.  Or you could require them to enter an address and [place a point on the map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Geocoder) from that address with [geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding).

Comment: Thanks jjclarkson but i am interested in locating the cities in the map

Answer (score 1):

If you are collecting the address of each registered user, you can get the latitude and longitude on the server-side through the [Google Maps HTTP Geocoding Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html).

You would use the following HTTP request:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Oxford+Street,+London&output=csv&sensor=false
```

Simply change the q parameter with your user's address.